# Layout options for web applications on mobile devices

Tags: css, ios, html, web-applications, layout

I am writing a web application for use on mobile touch devices, to begin with I am concentrating on the ipad. The application will contain a grid of thumbnail photographs, similar to google images.

I am really struggling with the layout of this site, I want the thumbnails to be equally spaced, with margins of the same size at the edges.

I have tried several methods, but have run into problems with all of them.

1.I tried designing the site with a fixed width of 960px, and laid out the thumbnails and their margins symmetrically for this width. This worked to a degree, but the ipad defaults the browser width to 980px, so the white space at the edges were larger than I would have liked.

2.The same as above, but I also specified:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=960, user-scalable=no" />
```

Everything now looks as it should on the ipad (in portrait), it's not too bad in landscape (I think the thumbnails are blown up, and a little pixelated). It displays fine on the desktop, but is unusable on the iphone as everything is too small.

3.To get round the above problem, and as suggested by apple [themselves](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.html) I tried swapping the above with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

With this, I get a sensible scale for both iPhone and iPad, but the problem is I can't get pixel perfection on my layouts, the white space at the left and right edges of the screen are not equal (because I am dealing with a grid of fixed width images, that do not fit a whole number of times into the space available)

Can anyone suggest the best approach please, I did consider using javascript to adjust the layout, but would prefer not to take this route.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A good attempt. I use this, see my link for an example, however this is only for iPhone mainly as the iPad is different. I would suggest seeing the FIXED layouts on:

http://www.gorgeouscouture.com/mobile/

http://m.oasis-stores.com/

http://m.asos.com/mt/www.asos.com

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="all, handheld" />
```

Notice I do not use the HTML5 heading. This is simply for other use of mobile devices. MyCSS:

```
body{width:320px;margin: 0px auto;min-height:356px;font-family:Georgia, Georgia, Arial, serif;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:50% 50%;text-align:center;background-color:#f4f8f9}
#b{position:relative;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;width:auto;height:auto;background:#fff;-moz-box-shadow:0 0 3px 3px #eaeaea;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 3px 3px #eaeaea;box-shadow:0 0 3px 3px #eaeaea}
#content{position:absolute;width:auto;height:auto;top:25%;background:#fff}
```

Notice the fixed width assignment though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply TheBlackBenzKid, I am curious as to why you set width=device-width and give a fixed width for your page?

Comment: I modified it now. And by the way. user-scalable=0 does not work on Windows Phone 7 for me, user-scalable=no and user-scalable=yes are working, the 1 and 0 are not. I have had to do this due some mobiles still show the bottom scroll. Another solution: http://jjeffryes.blogspot.com/2010/09/prevent-horizontal-scrolling-in-your.html

Comment: I would recommend using the links I sent above as they are fluid and not fixed. They still use the width=device-width options though - but it fits on fluid depending on screen size. I only do the later as the solution my client requires is a non fluid layout.

Comment: Just to update - these pages are no fluid. This answer cannot really be applied due to fluid.